# Flutter - Complex functions in initState() slowing down navigation and performance

Tags: android, performance, dart, flutter, background-process

I am working on this app, where you can navigate to a screen with a stateful widget that has a bunch complex functions that run in `initState()`.

Due to these functions, navigating to this screen takes close to two seconds after the Navigation function is triggered i.e It is very slow

My Code looks like this

```
@override
void initState(){
  someComplexHeavyFunctions();      

  super.initState();
}
```

Is there any way to make sure the navigation has completed (fast and smmothly) before running the function in `initState()` and also, maybe showing a loader while the functions are still processing after the screen has been navigated to?

like this:

[image]

Comment: You might want to move the operation to a background thread

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [compute](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/compute.html) function to do the calculation in a different isolate which runs on a different thread.

Comment: You can find a basic example in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16265#issuecomment-379000381, https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/background-parsing/ If you run into problems, please create more focused questions to that problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can call the initializing function and while awaiting for it, display the dialog.

This is a complete example:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Test"),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Text("Go"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context)
                .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => OtherPage()));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OtherPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OtherPageState createState() => _OtherPageState();
}

class _OtherPageState extends State<OtherPage> {
  bool initialized = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    initialize();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await showDialog<String>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => new AlertDialog(
              content: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  SizedBox(height: 40.0,),
                  Text("Performing task"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
      );
    });
  }

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    initialized = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () => true);
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body: new Center(
        child: initialized ? Text("Initialized") : Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```